# Smoothed particle hydrodynamics for solving diffusion equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, software

I'm a novice to the [smoothed particle hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) method and I'm keen to know how it can be used to solve partial differential equations. In particular I want to know how to discretize the spatial and time domains of the one-dimensional diffusion equation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \lambda \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

in order to solve it numerically. There is [one](https://doi.org/10.9790/1684-115196101) paper that discusses the diffusion equation but parts of it are opaque, especially how the authors go from the discretization and boundary/initial conditions to numerical results:

[image]

Is there any Matlab/Python code out there that uses SPH to solve the 1D diffusion equation? I don't need anything fancy or specialized modules (eg. [PySPH](https://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). I'm just looking for something concise that can produce simple line graphs like the above.

Answer (score 1):

For SPH, a generic quantity $A(\mathbf{r})$ is defined by,
$$A\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=\int A\left(\mathbf{r}'\right)W\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}',\,h\right)\,\mathrm{d}r'\tag{1}$$
where $W\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}',\,h\right)$ is the kernel associated with the problem. Using the set of particles, we have that
$$\langle A\left(\mathbf{r}_a\right)\rangle\approx\sum_b\frac{A_b}{\rho_b}W\left(\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b,\,h\right)$$
Using (1), the gradient is,
\begin{align}
  \nabla A\left(\mathbf{r}_a\right)&=\partial_\mathbf{r}\int A\left(\mathbf{r}'\right)W\left(\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}',\,h\right)\,\mathrm{d}r'\\
&\approx\sum_bm_b\frac{A_b}{\rho_b}\nabla_a W\left(\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b,\,h\right)
\end{align}
where the $a$ index indicates the derivative is w.r.t. the $\mathbf{r}_a$ coordinate.

A second derivative would be applied as,
$$\nabla^2 A\left(\mathbf{r}_a\right)\approx\sum_bm_b\frac{A_b}{\rho_b}\nabla^2_a W\left(\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b,h\right)\tag{diffusion}$$
which appears to be consistent with Equations (20) and (21) of your source. However, my understanding is that there are some stability arguments to utilize,
$$\nabla^2A\left(\mathbf{r}_a\right)\approx\sum_b\frac{m_b}{\rho_b}\left(A_b-A_a\right)\nabla^2_aW\left(\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b,h\right)$$
instead, which appears consistent with Equation (23) of your reference.
Sections 4.1 and 6.1 of [Daniel Price's `ndspmhd` paper](https://users.monash.edu.au/%7Edprice/ndspmhd/price-spmhd.pdf) might provide better insight than the document you referred to.

Since $W\left(\mathbf{r},\,h\right)$ is an analytic function known at compile time, you can easily compute both $\nabla W$ and $\nabla^2W$ analytically and save those functions within your codebase. While I've not written an SPH code myself, it seems to me that if you can write one for an advection equation, then it wouldn't be much more work to write it for the diffusion case; YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm aware there are good references that discuss the math and theory behind SPH. But I'm trying to find a detailed simple code to see how things work numerically (eg. like how to reproduce the graphs in my question).

Comment: Have you bothered to search Github for `1D SPH`? I see [~20 repos](https://github.com/search?q=1D+SPH) under that search. A few hundred if you [look for `smoothed particle`](https://github.com/search?q=smoothed+particle).

Comment: If I had found something useful in Github, I wouldn't be posting here would I? :)  There are many examples on Github, but I wanted to see if there were any tutorial-like examples not already there